# Find the smallest positive $N$ such that $N \equiv 3 \pmod{4}, N \equiv 2 \pmod{5}, N \equiv 6 \pmod{7}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the smallest positive $N$ such that
\begin{align*}
N &\equiv 3 \pmod{4}, \\
N &\equiv 2 \pmod{5}, \\
N &\equiv 6 \pmod{7}.
\end{align*}

I got 69 as the answer but with a check, it's not correct.  Am I at least close?  Could someone provide a solution?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$N = 4p + 3$$

$$N \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$$

$$4p + 3 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$$

$$4p \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$$

$$p \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$$

We find this by finding the inverse of 4 mod 5 (the 4 chosen is the coefficient of p on the left).

$$N = 4(1)+3 \pmod{4 * 5}$$

$$N \equiv 7 \pmod{20}$$

$$N = 20q + 7$$

$$N \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$$

$$20q + 7 \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$$

$$20q \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$$

$$6q \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$$

$$q \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$

$$N \equiv 20(1)+7 \pmod{20*7}$$

$$N \equiv 27 \pmod{140}$$

$$N = 27$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $N+1$ needs to be divisible by $4$ and $7$ thus $28$, and 
$$N+1 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$$

Look now for the smallest multiple of $28$ which has a remainder of $3$ when divided by $5$ and subtract 1.

**Hint 2:** $28=5\cdot 5+3$

Answer (score 0):

You first solve $\;\begin{cases}n\equiv3\mod 4,\\n\equiv2\mod 5.\end{cases}$.

For this you need a *Bézout's relation* between $4$ and $5$. We have one at hand: $\; 5-4=1$. Hence the solutions are:
$$n\equiv 3\cdot5-2\cdot 4=7\mod 4\cdot 5=20.$$
Then you solve $\;\begin{cases}N\equiv7\mod 20,\\N\equiv6\mod 7.\end{cases}$
A Bézout's relation between $20$ and $7$ is $\;3\cdot 7-20=1$. Hence the solutions are
$$N\equiv 7\cdot 3\cdot 7-6\cdot 20=27\pmod{140}.$$
The smallest positive integer in this congruence is $20$.

Answer (score 0):

$N+1$ has to be a multiple of $4\cdot 7= 28$ that is $\equiv 3\pmod{5}$.
Since $28$ is actually $\equiv 3\pmod{5}$, the smallest positive solution is given by $N=\color{red}{27}$.

Answer (score 0):

last digit of N due  to first condition should be either 1,3,5,7. due to second condition last digit should be either 7,2. so to satisfy both conditions it should end with 7. the smallest number ending with 7 satisfying third condition is 27.